# SSRS Hidden Parameter Logic Approach For STRING values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(MAX) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';


CREATE TABLE #PrvFilt(ID varchar(50))
DECLARE @xml xml
BEGIN
   SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @rpmProvider + '</X>') as xml)
   INSERT INTO #PrvFilt (ID)
   SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as value
   FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);
END;

SELECT  * from #PrvFilt
DROP TABLE #PrvFilt
```

Actual Output :

> Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar

Expected Output :

> 1. Prudhvi, raj
> 2. Lalith, Kumar

Comment: The question was not clear. On what criteria you are expecting the results like this.

Comment: Looks like you need to get the string split by commas and join them.  I'd say you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/10755978) and adapt it to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're not separating the individual names with XML.

Unfortunately, your first and last names are separated by commas and the whole names are also separated by commas.

**IF** your first and last names will **ALWAYS** have a **comma and a space** but the whole names will ONLY BE SEPARATED BY A COMMA, then this should work.

```
DECLARE @rpmProvider varchar(MAX) = 'Prudhvi, raj,Lalith, Kumar';

DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @XMT_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @XMT_TEXT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@rpmProvider, ', ', '|'), ',', '</X><X>'), '|', ', ')
SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + @XMT_TEXT + '</X>') as xml)


SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as value
FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N);
```